# android: search by ingredients

Tags: java, android

I'm making a recipe application. I got the search by recipe part working ok

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    protected ListView lv;
    protected ListAdapter adapter;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Cursor cursor;
    EditText et_db;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        db = (new DB_Recipe(this)).getWritableDatabase();
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
        et_db = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);

        try {
            cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM recipe ORDER BY name ASC", null);
            adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.isi_lv, cursor,
                    new String[] { "name", "ingredients", "img" }, new int[] {
                    R.id.tv_name, R.id.tvIngredients, R.id.imV });
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {
                    detail(position);

                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void search_db(View v) {
        String edit_db = et_db.getText().toString();
        if (!edit_db.equals("")) {
            try {
                cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM recipe WHERE name LIKE ?",
                        new String[] { "%" + edit_db + "%" });
                adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                        this,
                        R.layout.isi_lv,
                        cursor,
                        new String[] { "name", "ingredients", "img" },
                    new     int[] { R.id.tv_name, R.id.tvIngredients, R.id.imV });    
                if (adapter.getCount() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(
                            this,
                            "Recipe not found " + edit_db
                                    + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {    
                    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
        } else {
            try {
                cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM recipe ORDER BY name ASC",
                        null);
                adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                        this,
                        R.layout.isi_lv,
                        cursor,
                        new String[] { "name", "ingredients", "img" },
                        new int[] { R.id.tv_name, R.id.tvIngredients, R.id.imV });
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void detail(int position) {
        int im = 0;
        String _id = "";
        String name = "";
        String ingredients = "";
        String preparation = "";
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            cursor.moveToPosition(position);
            im = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("img"));
            name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
            ingredients = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ingredients"));
            preparation = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("preparation"));
        }

        Intent iIntent = new Intent(this, DB_Parse.class);
        iIntent.putExtra("dataIM", im);
        iIntent.putExtra("dataName", name);
        iIntent.putExtra("dataIngredients", ingredients);
        iIntent.putExtra("dataPreparation", preparation);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, iIntent);
        startActivityForResult(iIntent, 99);
    }

}
```

is there anyway that i can change this around so that you can search by ingredients instead of recipe or how would i go about doing so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want just to search by ingredients you can change your `public void search_db(View v)` the query where you search by recipe name:

```
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM recipe WHERE name LIKE ?", 
new String[] { "%" + edit_db + "%" });
```

to:

```
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM recipe WHERE ingredients LIKE ?", 
new String[] { "%" + edit_db + "%" });
```